# changing class name on click for duplicate menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/jJgRQ/145/)

I am trying to achieve something very simple when a listed item is clicked a new class has to be added to it, there are two identical menus, change of class needs to happen in both the menus even if the click occurs in single menu.

In the fiddle #e8e8e8 color is added to any listed item with class 'zm-active', currently it's on home and works for single menu, I want it to work on both the menus even if click happens on single menu.

Code:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.zetta-menu li').on('click', changeClass);
});

function changeClass() {
   $('.zetta-menu li').removeClass('zm-active');
    $(this).addClass('zm-active');
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="fixedbar">
     <ul onClick="" class="zetta-menu zm-response-switch zm-effect-slide-top">
            <li class="zm-active zm-content-full">
                <a href="#header-single-1">
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#about-10">
                    About
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#services-18">
                    Services
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#portfolio-19">
                    Portfolio
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#team-19">
                    Team
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#pricing-17">
                    Pricing
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#blog-19">
                    Blog
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact-1">
                    Contact
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul><!-- /.zetta-menu -->
</nav><!-- /#fixedbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-single-1 center" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-inner center">
        <ul onClick="" class="zetta-menu zm-response-switch zm-effect-slide-top">
            <li class="zm-active zm-content-full">
                <a href="#header-single-1">
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#about-10">
                    About
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#services-18">
                    Services
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#portfolio-19">
                    Portfolio
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#team-19">
                    Team
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#pricing-17">
                    Pricing
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#blog-19">
                    Blog
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact-1">
                    Contact
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul><!-- /.zetta-menu -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
</nav><!-- /.navbar-single-1 -->
```

I am not very through in javascript/jquery, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there something the links have in common? Of yourse! The href attribute (at least in your example).

So, you grab the href attribute of the link you clicked, by this attribute value you grab all links having the same href, and then you grab their parents (LI) in order to add class to them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.zetta-menu li a').click(function () {
         var itemsToChange = $('li a[href="'+$(this).attr('href')+'"]').parent(),
             allItems = $('.zetta-menu li');

        allItems.removeClass('zm-active');        

        itemsToChange.addClass('zm-active');
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jJgRQ/153/)